# Order area plots by their visible area, to maximize displayed information

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm trying to plot a series of area plots in front of each others (not stacked). The problem is they sometimes hide each other. Take a look at this example:

```
clc; close all; clear variables;
%% generate some data
p = {[0 1 0 1.1];
    [0 1 0 1];
    [0 1 0 0.2];
    [0.1 0.9 0 1.1]};
t = linspace(0, 2*pi);
y = cell2mat(cellfun(@(p) abs(p(1) + p(2)*sin(p(3)+p(4)*t)), p, 'UniformOutput', 0));

%% area plots without any order
n = size(p, 1);
C = lines(n);
h(1) = figure; hold on
for i=1:n
    area(t, y(i, :), 'facecolor', C(i, :))
end
```

[image]

I tried to sort surfaces by their area to get a better result:

```
%% order surfaces by their area
integral = sum(y, 2);
[~, order] = sort(integral, 'descend');
h(2) = figure; hold on
for i=1:n
    area(t, y(order(i), :), 'facecolor', C(order(i), :))
end
```

[image]

But the result is not satisfactory yet. I think the objective here is *to maximize the area of least visible surface*.

```
%% order surfaces by VISIBLE area
betterOrderIMO = [3 1 4 2 ];
h(3) = figure; hold on
for i=1:n
    area(t, y(betterOrderIMO(i), :), 'facecolor', C(betterOrderIMO(i), :))
end

%% test visible area
N = zeros(3, n);
C = floor(C*256);
for i=1:3
    f = getframe(h(i));
    I = (f.cdata);
    for j=1:n
        N(i, j) = sum(sum(I(:, :, 1)==C(j, 1)& I(:, :, 2)==C(j, 2)&I(:, :, 3)==C(j, 3)));
    end
end
min(N, [], 2)
```

[image]

> ans = -> No. of pixels of the least visible surface
>
> ```
>     2363 -> not ordered
>     3034 -> ordered by area
>     4146 -> ordered manually
> ```

I can run an optimization (e.g. `ga`), but that seems overkill.
So are there any other options to get the bast order of a series of area plots, that maximizes the area of least visible plot?

Comment: if this is for visualization, have you considered setting 'facealpha' to add some transparency to the area objects that are in front? or maybe you are interested in the general problem of stacking these objects so that the stack has certain optimal properties (ie least amount of hidden area)

Comment: @Azim, thanks for your suggestion. I've already tried making area objects transparent, but that makes things even more complicated. Not only my real data fluctuates a lot, I also have to show 15 to 20 curves in one figure. Transparenting surfaces results in the creation of areas with new colors that are not easy to interpret. So I have no choice but to optimize the order of the levels.

Comment: @Azim I actually implemented it using `ga` and will post the result here as soon as I get a chance. But I still think that it is overkill to use meta-heuristics to solve such a problem. Worse, they sometimes converge to suboptimal responses, in which some curves are completely hidden behind others. So I wonder if there are straightforward and possibly analytical approaches to this issue.

Comment: good luck. do you need to plot the curves as 'areas', why not just plot the boundary in different colors. Unfortunately, I'm not sure what else to suggest. Hopefully, someone else may have ideas for you.

Comment: @Azim thanks. The main problem is that there is too much data to display in one figure. I tried many things. The area plot, despite all its flaws, still gives the best sense of changes of curves beside each other.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your problem is to display a lot of signals/functions at the same time, based on your comments. How about you use a 3-dimensional perspective?

```
%% generate some data
p = {[0 1 0 1.1];
    [0 1 0 1];
    [0 1 0 0.2];
    [0.1 0.9 0 1.1]};
t = linspace(0, 2*pi);
y = cell2mat(cellfun(@(p) abs(p(1) + p(2)*sin(p(3)+p(4)*t)), p, 'UniformOutput', 0));

%% area plots without any order
n = size(p, 1);
C = lines(n);
h(1) = figure; hold on
for i=1:n
    patch( i*ones([1 numel(t)+2]), [t(1) t t(end)], [0 y(i,:) 0], C(i,:) );
end
view(3);
grid on;
```

[image: Three-dimensional view, filled faces.]

You may want to replace the tick labels along the *x* axis with something more meaningful.

Another option would be this:

```
%% generate some data
p = {[0 1 0 1.1];
    [0 1 0 1];
    [0 1 0 0.2];
    [0.1 0.9 0 1.1]};
t = linspace(0, 2*pi);
y = cell2mat(cellfun(@(p) abs(p(1) + p(2)*sin(p(3)+p(4)*t)), p, 'UniformOutput', 0));

%% area plots without any order
n = size(p, 1);
C = lines(n);
h(1) = figure;
h_patch=waterfall( [t(1) t t(end)], 1:n, [zeros([n 1]) y zeros([n 1])], (1:n).'.*ones([n numel(t)+2]) );
colormap(C);
set(h_patch,'FaceColor','none');
set(h_patch,'LineWidth',2);
view(-15,75);
```

[image: Three-dimensional view, transparent faces.]